# The Dance of Love?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> Romeo and Juliett are sitting idly in the lobby of their hotel awaiting their chaperone for the evening. Romeo takes a sip from his glass of whiskey as he watches his wife consume pages of abstract algebra voraciously from a recently published book. They both have their intellectual vices (his obsession is with model tanks) but to him, she is unique because her incredible intelligence is matched only by her indescribable beauty. He recalls, fondly, the day he asked her to marry him. 
>  *It was the end of November, and they had been staying in a remote ski lodge in the north-west of the country then known as Czechoslovakia. He recalls the smell of their quaint double room and kitchenette filled with furniture from Ikea. Romeo had cooked up a meal far beyond his usual standard, delighting olfactory senses, which made Juli suspicious that something was up. Apart from the marked improvement in his cooking ability, he had lit several yankee candles around the room and his demeanour was messier, rather more distracted, than usual. 
>
> He was so scared about how she would react, this would not be her first proposal after all. Juli married an awful man when she was young, but filed for divorce just a year later. Her ex - Ray - moved away to work for some Eastern metropolitan government, leaving Juli in the lurch. However, Romeo was a better man than Ray and when he produced the thin diamond ring, she voiced an ecstatic "yes!" and Romeo jumped into the air like a victorious zulu warrior. 
>
>  That evening they danced their favourite style of dance which is of course the...* 
> Romeo's daydreaming is interrupted by the arrival of their chaperone. The couple rise to meet him. Romeo notices the nametag on his uniform says 'Charlie' and he shakes the man's hand in greeting. He links arms with Juliett and gazes fondly into her eyes as they set off into the night to celebrate their anniversary.

**What is the couple's favourite style of dance?**

Comment: If they are married why do they need a chaperone??

Comment: @DhDd I think the word chaperone has a broader meaning these days. A google search brings up the definition "a person who accompanies and looks after another person or group of people." Although I do understand the confusion. Perhaps 'tour guide' might be a better choice?

Comment: @hexomino:  Perhaps you meant "chauffeur" instead of "chaperone"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think it's

> Foxtrot

since it's

> the only letter of the NATO alphabet not mentioned in the text:
>
>  me**al fa**r
>  alge**bra vo**raciously
>  **Charlie**
>  mo**del ta**nks
>  Cz**echo**slovakia
>  (?)
>  delightin**g olf**actory
>  **hotel**
>  th**in dia**mond
>  **Juliet**t
>  s**ki lo**dge
>  Ju**li ma**rried
>  fro**m Ike**a
>  **November**
>  s**o scar**ed
>  u**p apa**rt
>  uni**que bec**ause
>  **Romeo**
>  mes**sier ra**ther
>  metropoli**tan go**vernment
>  **uniform**
>  **victor**ious
>  **whiskey**
>  **ex Ray**
>  **yankee**
>  **zulu**

Comment: Whilst I think this is the correct line of reasoning, I can think of other letters (and dances) not mentioned

Comment: Ooooohhhhhhhhhh

Comment: um, don't forget her ex - Ray

Comment: Spot on, well done!